# Does the Minecraft Realms Friend Count include the Host?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-realms

I have a 10 "friend" Realm, does that mean me and 9 or 10 other players can play? Does being the host count as a "friend" slot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting the store page:

> Pick this option to own a realm which supports simultaneous play for you and ten friends.

It would be you and ten other people, so 11 players (including you) total.